# Insert into Table select result set from stored procedure but column count is not same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, plsql

I need something like that which is of course not working.

```
insert into Table1
(
  Id,
  Value
)
select Id, value from
(

  exec MySPReturning10Columns

)
```

I wanted to populate Table1 from result set returned by `MySPReturning10Columns`. Here the SP is returning 10 columns and the table has just 2 columns.

The following way works as long as table and result set from SP have same number of columns but in my case they are not same.

```
INSERT INTO TableWith2Columns 
  EXEC usp_MySPReturning2Columns;
```

Also, I want to avoid adding "." as linked server just to make openquery and openrowset work anyhow.

Is there a way not to have define table strucutre in temp table (all columns with datatypes and lenght)? Something like CTE.

Comment: Is there a way not to have define table strucutre in temp table (all columns with datatypes and lenght)? Something like CTE.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a temporary table as a go-between:

```
insert into #TempTable exec MySP
insert into Table1 (id, value) select id, value from #TempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the problem in two steps by doing the insert from the stored procedure into a temporary table, then do the insert selecting just the columns you want from the temporary table.

Information on temporary tables: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables

Answer (score 0):

-- Well, declare a temp table or a table var, depending on the number of rows expected 
-- from the SP. This table will be basically the result set of your SP.

```
DECLARE @spResult AS TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    VALUE FLOAT,
    ....
);
```

-- Get the result set of the SP into the temp table.

```
INSERT @spResult EXEC STORED_PROC;
```

-- Now you can query the SP's result set for ID and Value;

```
INSERT Table1 (ID, VALUE) 
SELECT ID, VALUE FROM @spResult;
```

Comment: `CREATE` a #temp table, or `DECLARE` a table @variable. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to create a temporary table, you can do it with single query by creating temporary view like this

```
with tempView as EXEC MySPReturning10Columns insert into Table1 select id, value from tempView
```

The temporary view disappears as soon as the statement finishes execution

Comment: This could be best solution but I am getting error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

Comment: It looks like that by 'temporary view' you mean a CTE (Common Table Expression). That won't work - a CTE query definition (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx) must conform to the same constraints as a View, i.e. it must be a SELECT statement (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).